# Show that the equation, $\tan(i \log\frac{ x−iy }{x+iy} ) = 2$ represents the rectangular hyperbola $x^2 − y^2 = xy$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that the equation, $\;\tan\left(i \log\dfrac{x−iy}{x+iy}\right)=2\;$ represents the rectangular hyperbola $\;x^2 − y^2 = xy\;$.

What I could do is to simplify the expression

$\tan\left(i\log\dfrac{x−iy}{x+iy}\right)=2\quad$ to the following one :$$\tan\left(i\log\dfrac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}\right)\;.$$

I don’t know how to proceed further.  Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider the following identity:

$$\tan(i\ln(X)) \equiv \frac{i \left(X^2-1\right)}{X^2+1}$$

where in your case $X = \frac{x-iy}{x+iy}$.

Substitute, arrange and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ln\dfrac{x-iy}{x+iy}=2it$  where $t$ is real

$$\implies\dfrac{x-iy}{x+iy}=\dfrac{e^{it}}{e^{-it}}$$

Applying [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/#componendo-and-dividendo-theorems)   $$\dfrac x{iy}=\dfrac{\cos t}{-i\sin t}\implies\tan t=-\dfrac yx$$

$$2=\tan(i(2it))=\tan(-2t)=-\tan2t=\dfrac{2\tan t}{1-\tan^2t}=?$$